# Loading css through a javascript file, not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use a JS file to load css based on the scroll location. I have a header div with three nested divs that this JS is modifying. here is what I have.

JS:

```
var titles = [
'Pick 1',
'Pick 2',
'Pick 3',
'Pick 4',
'Pick 5',
'"Quote 1"',
'"Quote 2"',
'"Quote 3"',
'"Quote 4"',
'"Quote 5"',
'Footer Title',
''
];

$(window).scroll(function(){
var pos = $(this).scrollTop(); 
var slideTitle1 =  $("#slideTitle1").offset().top;
var slideTitle2 =  $("#slideTitle2").offset().top;
var slideTitle3 =  $("#slideTitle3").offset().top;
var slideTitle4 =  $("#slideTitle4").offset().top;
var slideTitle5 =  $("#slideTitle5").offset().top;
var slideFooter =  $("#slideFooter").offset().top;

if( pos < slideTitle1 - 300) {
    $('#title').slideUp();
}
if( pos > slideTitle1 - 300) {
    $('#title').slideDown();
}
if( pos > slideTitle1 - 300) {
    $('#textBox').text(titles[0]);
    $('#quoteBox').text(titles[5]);

}
if( pos > slideTitle2 - 100) {
    $('#textBox').text(titles[1]);
    $('#quoteBox').text(titles[6]);
}
if( pos > slideTitle3 - 100) {
    $('#textBox').text(titles[2]);
    $('#quoteBox').text(titles[7]);
}
if( pos > slideTitle4 - 100) {
    $('#textBox').text(titles[3]);
    $('#quoteBox').text(titles[8]);
}
if( pos > slideTitle5 - 100) {
    $('#textBox').text(titles[4]);
    $('#quoteBox').text(titles[9]);
}
if( pos > slideFooter - 50) {
    $('#textBox').text(titles[11]);
    $('#quoteBox').text(titles[10])
    $('#quoteBox').css("font-size", "35px", "text-align", "center");
    $('#textBox').css("display", "none");
    $('#rateBox').css("display", "none");
}
if( pos < slideFooter - 50) {
    $('#quoteBox').css("font-size", "30px", "text-align", "left");
    $('#textBox').css("display", "block")
    $('#rateBox').css("display", "block")
}
});
```

CSS:

```
#title { 
width: 100%; 
background: black; 
height: 85px;   
position: fixed;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 10px;
font-size: 30px; 
color: white;
box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
z-index: 1001; 
display: none;
} 

#textBox {
width: 250px;
height: 40px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-left: 25px;
padding-top: inherit;
float: left;
}

#quoteBox {
width: 50%;
 height: 40px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: inherit;
}

.rateBox {
width: 75px;
height: 75px;
float: right;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-right: 25px;
border: green 1px solid;
background-image: url(../img/rating/rating5.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.5 {
background-image: url(../img/rating/rating5.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.4.5 {
background-image: url(../img/rating/rating4.5.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.4 {
background-image: url(../img/rating/rating4.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.3.5 {
background-image: url(../img/rating/rating3.5.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.3 {
background-image: url(../img/rating/rating3.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Source:

```
<div id="title">
<div id="textBox">
</div>
<div class="rateBox">
</div>
<div id="quoteBox">
</div>
</div>
```

but when I try to add **$('#rateBox').css("background", "url('../img/rating/rating3.png')");** to if's 3-7 it does not do anything. in fact it seems to undo the default white background color I have set. I tried everything I could like of so far to fix this but no combination works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The URL, is it relative to the HTML file and not to the JS/CSS files? That's crucial.

Comment: You're using a shorthand CSS syntax, which will overwrite your background-color property with the default for shorthand (transparent). Try just background-image:url() instead.

Comment: Would it not be simpler to have a regular css file with the different styles given different classes, then only change the class according to scroll, rather than all of the styles? It would avoid the strangeness of altering a background image through JavaScript.

Comment: Ok so i cant even get this to adapt witch is what i need to do i think, nothing is working. [Exampile](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/ayGwn/3/)

Comment: your code needs for loops. `for(var i=0, el; i<...; i++) { el =  $("#slideTitle" + i).offset().top; ... }` etc. As you have it now is a minefield: even if you fix things in one spot, you still have to fix things in ten other spots. That's not maintainable.

Comment: @ Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans ok, i am not the best with JS so can i start off by whats right? is the CSS right, are the div nested right, or are we only talking about the JS right now?

Comment: i see your point as a whole but i dont understand how a for loop fixes anything because each of my three div's needs to load something new in 6 different sections, is a for loop going to fix the minefield. i think that it would only make the code more compact. but really the root of this issue is i cant seem to load a png. background image to div "rateBox" with any method i have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer to this issue Boldewyn you may have got it because changing my file path from ../img/rating/rating5.png to rating/rating5.png worked and its good to go. I also, in side the site folder moved the rating folder out of the img folder into the level as the index.html file.

@Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I am trying to understand you loop but with out some more detailed code and more of an explanation as to how loops fix the minefield and make content anymore manageable then they are now I cant make heads or tails of your post. IMO the array text is easyly updatable, the location they get pluged into never change, and if the rating changed all you have to do is change the filename from ratingX.png to the number you want it to be. the nameing convention I use solves that.